# wordpress wp-admin showing white screen with no error

Tags: wp-admin

Suddenly my wordpress site wp-admin stop working. When I will try to access wp-admin it will display white screen. I have deactivated all plugin by rename plugin folder , also uploaded fresh wp-admin and wp-include folder but same problem. I have also enable debug mode true in config file

I have also replace wp-config file with fresh file but no luck.

When I will try to access with wp-login.php it will work but showing:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output

Even my browser cookie is already enabled.

It will be greatful if any one help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You can find your solution from [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/208878/login-page-error-cookies-are-blocked-due-to-unexpected-output/214139#214139)

Comment: can't find any solution

Comment: Does fresh WordPress installation on the same hosting has the same problem?

Comment: I have not tried with fresh installation but this problem will come suddenly. Before few days every thing was fine

Comment: Ok, Did you check your error log? May be there is any clue.  Please find that.

Comment: I have checked but error log doesn't exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34242/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-ravinder-kumar).