# ERROR: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output - ultimate solution

Tags: login, errors

I know this problem can happen but I need ultimate solution.

My main error is:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked due to unexpected output. For help, please
>   see this documentation or try the support forums.

Now, I do things from this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/213549/82023

Also do this things like cheking source of `wp-login.php`, examine is there is some whitespace or similar problem in certain files update complete installation manualy and same problems.

What's missing?

I hosted in GoDaddy

Thanks!

Comment: The "ultimate solution" is called debugging. :)

Comment: Check this for answers: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166181/cant-log-in-error-cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser-you?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to enable PHP errors or look on it in an error log.
2. There you will find a file and row where input was started.
3. If it will show you that input was started in row #1 that means this file has unprintable symbols before

   ```
   <?php
   ```